# C++ Header file inclusion

Tags: php, g++, php-extension

I am new to coding PHP extensions. And i was tryin the following snippet in a .cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Zend/zend.h"

using namespace std;

void describe_zval(zval *foo)
{
    if (foo->type == IS_NULL)
    {
        php_printf("The variable is NULL");
    }
    else
    {
        php_printf("The variable is of type %d", foo->type);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

The variable `zval` (which is a struct )is present in `/usr/local/src/php-5.4.11/Zend/zend.h`

Compilation

```
g++ -I /usr/local/src/php-5.4.11 -I /usr/local/src/php-5.4.11/Zend try.cpp
```

This gives the error

```
In file included from /usr/local/src/php-5.4.11/Zend/zend_alloc.h:27:0,
                 from /usr/local/src/php-5.4.11/Zend/zend.h:237,
                 from try.c:2:
/usr/local/src/php-5.4.11/Zend/../TSRM/TSRM.h:20:26: fatal error: tsrm_config.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

tsrm_config.h is present in `/usr/local/src/php-5.4.11/`

How do i include the subdirectories under `/usr/local/src/php-5.4.11/` since the compilation process requires many files located in several subdirectories of `/usr/local/src/php-5.4.11/`

Comment: well, by adding it as a library/include thingy in g++ will deffinatly help: `-I : Sets the path to the include files. | 
-L : Sets the path to the libraries.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the php-5.4.11 directory, you should also include Zend, main, TSRM (if you want to develop your extension on a thread-safe server). I mean you should have:`-I /usr/local/src/php-5.4.11/main` `I /usr/local/src/php-5.4.11/Zend` `I /usr/local/src/php-5.4.11/TSRM`, you can create a makefile for including these directories. By the way, why don't you use SWIG for creating your wrapper code? you should try that.